# Javascript rotate img when display

Tags: javascript, css, image, events, rotation

I have a script which display an img when we are attack by a monster.
So, the image is always in display="none" and when there is a monster it switch to      display="";

I want the image do a 360° flip when it switch from display:none to display.

html : `<img id="monster" style="display:none;">`

js : `var skinMonster = document.getElementById('monster');`

When we are in fight, i do `skinMonster.style.display="";`

When the fight is over, i do `skinMonster.style.display="none";`

I don't how to detect the moment when the style change to rotate the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a CSS class at the same point where you change the display.

```
.rotate {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;

    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;

    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg); 
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);

    overflow:hidden;

    }
```

Which I slightly modified from this blog post: http://blog.vivekv.com/rotate-image-360deg-when-mouse-hover-using-css-3.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a CSS transition for the rotation.

**HTML**

```
<img id="monster" src="http://www.avatarsdb.com/avatars/mike_monsters_inc.jpg" />
<button id="show">Show monster</button>
```

**CSS**

```
#monster {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}

#monster.show {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var monsterImg = document.getElementById('monster'),
    showMonsterButton = document.getElementById('show');

showMonsterButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

    monsterImg.classList.add('show');

});
```

JSFiddle for demo purposes: http://jsfiddle.net/9wkA7/